# " Cannot find name 'require'" when trying to integrate firebase-admin in angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-admin

struggling with " Cannot find name 'require'" Error when trying to add firebase-admin to my project 
I have tryed :

- npm install @types/node --save-dev
- adding   "types": [ "node" ],

I'm setting it up in my appComponent.ts like this:

```
constructor(private  afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private  afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase) {
var admi = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require('key.json');
admi.initializeApp({
  credential: admi.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://pami-16c0f.firebaseio.com"
});
```

-key.json file is in app-folder (same folder as app.component.ts ofc)

Error says something about firebase-storage which I'm not intending to use and did not add to my project-which makes that just more confusing:s, I'm adding a screen shot of what exacly the error 'says':
[image]

Comment: Will you please post whole app.component.ts file ?

Comment: The Firebase Admin SDK gives full administrative access to your Firebase project. It is meant to be used in a trusted environment, such as a server you control or Cloud Functions. Using it in client-facing application code gives the user of that app full administrative access to your project, which is likely to be a security risk.

Answer (score 2):

---

Export json data :

**ServiceAccount.ts**

```
export const serviceAccount: any = { your json data };
```

**appComponent.ts**

```
import { serviceAccount } from './ServiceAccount';
```

---

Please try this code :

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import { serviceAccount } from './ServiceAccount';

constructor(private  afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private  afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase) {
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://pami-16c0f.firebaseio.com"
});
}
```

Comment: -hi, I've just created whole new project to try to make it work so there is nothing now in my app.component.ts file  (no arguments in constructor eaither) but Error is still the same  - tryed your aproach but getting "Cannot find module key.json"

Comment: That means you have solved the admin issue now you are just facing the key.json file issue , create one file "serviceAccount.ts" that export const serviceAccount = { your json data } and then import it as.
import serviceAccount from "serviceAccount";

Comment: still the same Error "Cannot find module 'serviceAccount'  "  even though when it comes up as a suggestion when I'm typing the import...:S

Comment: Dude you need to learn some basics, please try it by your self, there is nothing hard init. Once you solve this it all done. @pb4now

Comment: yea-comming from android so confused as hell but will make it work:) -ty

Comment: @pb4now, okay I have updated my answer, please check , I think this can help, please dont forgot to upvote if helpful and also accept the answer if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156845/discussion-between-pb4now-and-vivek-doshi).